# No "configure" available in Git version (1.13) of graph-tool

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, configure, graph-tool

I have downloaded graph-tool v1.13 from Git (https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool ). The `INSTALL` file instructs me to run `./configure` in the source code's directory however the `configure` file does not exist. What do I need to do to install it?

EDIT: If I run `autoconf` in the directory I get the following messages:

```
sh: 1: git: not found
sh: 1: git: not found
configure.ac:20: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:22: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_CC_C_O
configure.ac:33: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_STATIC
configure.ac:55: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_RESULT
configure.ac:87: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONDITIONAL
configure.ac:188: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_PYTHON
configure.ac:193: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PYTHON_DEVEL
```

I am not entirely sure what to do about these messages or if they are expected behaviour, but if I run the thus created `configure` file it returns the following error:

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `./autogen.sh` solves the issue. This generates a `configure` file.